# How can I make css generate an ellipsis on text overflow?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I'm working with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/entJc/).  I would like the `<p>Super long words here</p>` to look like `Super lon...` instead of showing the full text.  I tried adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But it didn't work.  How can I get my overflow text to end in an ellipsis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a width to achieve this effect, like this:

```
.pClass p {
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:20px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/entJc/1/)**